# Puppet module: No set of title patterns matched the title "name"

Tags: puppet

So I'm very very new with puppet modules, and decided to create one to try it out.

I want in my environment manifest to run something like that:

```
manifest_name { 'some_title': 
   ensure => present
}
```

However when I run the agent I get:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: No set of title patterns matched the title "some_title".
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

I thought I needed to add inside my type file:

```
newparam(:name, :namevar => true) {
    desc "The name of the manifest."
}
```

but that didn't change a thing?

What am I missing?

Thanks,

---

Edit:

So the client is signed for sure.
Still not sure what happened there I just restarted the puppet master and the real error was shown.

Comment: can you confirm the puppet server has signed the certification for the client? Can you run the command `puppet cert list -all`, did you see the client? Can you put the output in your question?

Comment: There is no the type of `manifest_name`, maybe you'd like to use [notify](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#notify)

Comment: Funny. Of course it wasn't manifest_name but an actual code. Don't worry. BTW - I already edited the question - after the puppet master restart it worked.

Comment: No problem. Happy to hear the problem fixed.